# Bounds for type parameter of FunctionK

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I'm using `cats` [FreeMonad](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html). Here's a simplified version of the algebra:

```
sealed trait Op[A]

object Op {
    final case class Get[T](name: String) extends Op[T]

    type OpF[A] = Free[Op, A]

    def get[T](name: String): OpF[T] = liftF[Op, T](Get[T](name))
}
```

One of the interpreters will be a wrapper around a third-party library, called `Client` here which its `get` method's signature is similar to:

```
class Client {
    def get[O <: Resource](name: String)
        (implicit f: Format[O], d: Definition[O]): Future[O] = ???
}
```

My question is how can I encode that requirement in my implementation?

```
class FutureOp extends (Op ~> Future) {
    val client = new Client()

    def apply[A](fa: Op[A]): Future[A] =
        fa match {
            case Get(name: String) =>
                client.get[A](name)
        }
}
```

I tried things like introducing bounds to my `apply` (like `apply[A <: Resource : Format : Definition]`) which didn't work.

I understand that `FunctionK` is to transform values of first-order-kinded types, but is there anyway in which I can encode the requirements of the type parameter?

I intend to use it like:

```
def run[F[_]: Monad, A](intp: Op ~> F, op: OpF[A]): F[A] = op.foldMap(intp)

val p: Op.OpF[Foo] = Op.get[Foo]("foo")

val i = new FutureOp()

run(i, d)
```

Comment: One idea would be to go first from `Op[A]` to a `({type L[A] = ReaderT[Future, (Format[A], Definition[A]), A]})#L` and then finally from that to a `Future[A]`. Not sure if it works, but it's what I would try. In other words, transform to a Reader to obtain the (implicit) params and just then call the `Client` method.

Comment: I've tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't work due to the `Resource` subtype constraint: https://gist.github.com/igstan/3e90f8c704b42a97b9de9d66a67feb5d

Comment: Can you please update the question with a sample of how you'd use the `Op` DSL?

Comment: @ionuț-g-stan just did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(My original answer contained the same idea, but apparently it did not provide enough implementation details. This time, I wrote a more detailed step-by-step guide with a discussion of each intermediate step. Every section contains a separate compilable code snippet.)*

---

**TL;DR**

1. Implicits are required for each type `T` that occurs in `get[T]`, therefore they must be inserted and stored when the DSL-program is *constructed*, not when it is *executed*. This solves the problem with the implicits.
2. There is a general strategy for gluing a natural transformation `~>` from several *restricted natural transformations* `trait RNT[R, F[_ <: R], G[_]]{ def apply[A <: R](x: F[A]): G[A] }` using pattern matching. This solves the problem with the `A <: Resource` type bound. Details below.

---

In your question, you have two separate problems:

1. implicit `Format` and `Definition`
2. `<: Resource`-type bound

I want to treat each of these two problems in isolation, and provide a reusable solution strategy for both. I will then apply both strategies to your problem.

My answer below is structured as follows:

1. First, I will summarize your question as I understand it.
2. Then I will explain what to do with the implicits, ignoring the type bound.
3. Then I will deal with the type bound, this time ignoring the implicits.
4. Finally, I apply both strategies to your particular problem.

Henceforth, I assume that you have `scalaVersion` `2.12.4`, the dependencies

```
libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-free" % "1.0.1"
```

and that you insert

```
import scala.language.higherKinds
```

where appropriate.
Note that the solution strategies are not specific to this particular scala version or the `cats` library.

---

#### The setup

The goal of this section is to make sure that I'm solving the right problem, and also to provide very simple mock-up definitions 
of `Resource`, `Format`, `Client` etc., so that this answer is self-contained
and compilable.

I assume that you want to build a little domain specific language using the `Free` monad.
Ideally, you would like to have a DSL that looks approximately like this (I've used the names `DslOp` for the operations and `Dsl` for the generated free monad):

```
import cats.free.Free
import cats.free.Free.liftF

sealed trait DslOp[A]
case class Get[A](name: String) extends DslOp[A]

type Dsl[A] = Free[DslOp, A]
def get[A](name: String): Dsl[A] = liftF[DslOp, A](Get[A](name))
```

It defines a single command `get` that can get objects of type `A` given a string 
name.

Later, you want to interpret this DSL using a `get` method provided by some `Client`
that you cannot modify:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

trait Resource
trait Format[A <: Resource]
trait Definition[A <: Resource]

object Client {
  def get[A <: Resource](name: String)
    (implicit f: Format[A], d: Definition[A]): Future[A] = ???
}
```

Your problem is that the `get` method of the `Client` has a type bound, and that 
it requires additional implicits.

#### Dealing with implicits when defining interpreter for the Free monad

Let's first pretend that the `get`-method in client requires implicits, but
ignore the type bound for now:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

trait Format[A]
trait Definition[A]

object Client {
  def get[A](name: String)(implicit f: Format[A], d: Definition[A])
  : Future[A] = ???
}
```

Before we write down the solution, let's briefly discuss why you cannot supply all 
the necessary implicits when you are calling the `apply` method in `~>`.

- When passed to `foldMap`, the `apply` of `FunctionK` is supposed
  to be able to cope with arbitrarily long programs of type `Dsl[X]` to produce `Future[X]`.
- Arbitrarily long programs of type `Dsl[X]` can contain an unlimited number of 
  `get[T1]`, ..., `get[Tn]` commands for different types `T1`, ..., `Tn`.
- For each of those `T1`, ..., `Tn`, you have to get a `Format[T_i]` and `Definition[T_i]` somewhere.
- These implicit arguments must be supplied by the compiler.
- When you interpret the entire program of type `Dsl[X]`, only the type `X` but not the types `T1`, ..., `Tn` are available, 
  so the compiler cannot insert all the necessary `Definition`s and `Format`s at the call site.
- Therefore, all the `Definition`s and `Format`s must be supplied as implicit parameters to `get[T_i]` 
  when you are *constructing* the `Dsl`-program, not when you are *interpreting* it.

The solution is to add `Format[A]` and `Definition[A]` as members to the `Get[A]` case class,
and make the definition of `get[A]` with `lift[DslOp, A]` accept these two additional implicit 
parameters:

```
import cats.free.Free
import cats.free.Free.liftF
import cats.~>

sealed trait DslOp[A]
case class Get[A](name: String, f: Format[A], d: Definition[A]) 
  extends DslOp[A]

type Dsl[A] = Free[DslOp, A]
def get[A](name: String)(implicit f: Format[A], d: Definition[A])
: Dsl[A] = liftF[DslOp, A](Get[A](name, f, d))
```

Now, we can define the first approximation of the `~>`-interpreter, which at least 
can cope with the implicits:

```
val clientInterpreter_1: (DslOp ~> Future) = new (DslOp ~> Future) {
  def apply[A](op: DslOp[A]): Future[A] = op match {
    case Get(name, f, d) => Client.get(name)(f, d)
  }
}
```

#### Type bounds in case classes defining the DSL-operations

Now, let's deal with the type bound in isolation. Suppose that your `Client`
doesn't need any implicits, but imposes an additional bound on `A`:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

trait Resource
object Client {
  def get[A <: Resource](name: String): Future[A] = ???
}
```

If you tried to write down the `clientInterpreter` in the same way as in the
previous example, you would notice that the type `A` is too general, and that
you therefore cannot work with the contents of `Get[A]` in `Client.get`.
Instead, you have to find a scope where the additional type information `A <: Resource` 
is not lost. One way to achieve it is to define an `accept` method on `Get` itself.
Instead of a completely general natural transformation `~>`, this `accept` method will 
be able to work with *natural transformations with restricted domain*.
Here is a trait to model that:

```
trait RestrictedNat[R, F[_ <: R], G[_]] {
  def apply[A <: R](fa: F[A]): G[A]
}
```

It looks almost like `~>`, but with an additional `A <: R` restriction. Now we 
can define `accept` in `Get`:

```
import cats.free.Free
import cats.free.Free.liftF
import cats.~>

sealed trait DslOp[A]
case class Get[A <: Resource](name: String) extends DslOp[A] {
  def accept[G[_]](f: RestrictedNat[Resource, Get, G]): G[A] = f(this)
}

type Dsl[A] = Free[DslOp, A]
def get[A <: Resource](name: String): Dsl[A] = 
  liftF[DslOp, A](Get[A](name))
```

and write down the second approximation of our interpreter, without any
nasty type-casts:

```
val clientInterpreter_2: (DslOp ~> Future) = new (DslOp ~> Future) {
  def apply[A](op: DslOp[A]): Future[A] = op match {
    case g @ Get(name) => {
      val f = new RestrictedNat[Resource, Get, Future] {
        def apply[X <: Resource](g: Get[X]): Future[X] = Client.get(g.name)
      }
      g.accept(f)
    }
  }
}
```

This idea can be generalized to an arbitrary number of type constructors `Get_1`, ...,
`Get_N`, with type restrictions `R1`, ..., `RN`. The general idea corresponds to 
the construction of a piecewise defined natural transformation from smaller 
pieces that work only on certain subtypes.

#### Applying both solution strategies to your problem

Now we can combine the two general strategies into one solution for
your concrete problem:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import cats.free.Free
import cats.free.Free.liftF
import cats.~>

// Client-definition with both obstacles: implicits + type bound
trait Resource
trait Format[A <: Resource]
trait Definition[A <: Resource]

object Client {
  def get[A <: Resource](name: String)
    (implicit fmt: Format[A], dfn: Definition[A])
  : Future[A] = ???
}


// Solution:
trait RestrictedNat[R, F[_ <: R], G[_]] {
  def apply[A <: R](fa: F[A]): G[A]
}

sealed trait DslOp[A]
case class Get[A <: Resource](
  name: String,
  fmt: Format[A],
  dfn: Definition[A]
) extends DslOp[A] {
  def accept[G[_]](f: RestrictedNat[Resource, Get, G]): G[A] = f(this)
}

type Dsl[A] = Free[DslOp, A]
def get[A <: Resource]
  (name: String)
  (implicit fmt: Format[A], dfn: Definition[A])
: Dsl[A] = liftF[DslOp, A](Get[A](name, fmt, dfn))


val clientInterpreter_3: (DslOp ~> Future) = new (DslOp ~> Future) {
  def apply[A](op: DslOp[A]): Future[A] = op match {
    case g: Get[A] => {
      val f = new RestrictedNat[Resource, Get, Future] {
        def apply[X <: Resource](g: Get[X]): Future[X] = 
          Client.get(g.name)(g.fmt, g.dfn)
      }
      g.accept(f)
    }
  }
}
```

Now, the `clientInterpreter_3` can cope with both problems: the type-bound-problem is dealt with
by defining a `RestrictedNat` for each case class that imposes an upper bound on its type arguments,
and the implicits-problem is solved by adding an implicit parameter list to DSL's `get`-method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I don't understand is how changing the `get` in DSL fixes the issue of calling `client.get` with `[A]`? The problem is the `A`s boundaries aren't specified in `apply`.

Comment: The problem is if I don't specify the type parameter in `client.get` I'll get `diverging implicit expansion` error.

Comment: And if I just say `client.get[A]`, I'll get `type arguments [A] do not conform to method get's type parameter bounds [O <: Resource]`

Comment: @racetrack Why would you want to not specify type parameter in `client.get`? Once the `Format` and `Definition` are stored in `Get[A <: Resource](name: String, fmt: Format[A], dfn: Definition[A])`, your interpreter `~>` can call `Client.get[A](name)(fmt, dfn)` explicitly.

Comment: well, the problem is that wouldn't work. It throws an error that it doesn't conform to method get's type parameter bounds `[O <: Resource]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166480/discussion-between-andrey-tyukin-and-racetrack).

Comment: @racetrack Added a much more detailed solution. The original answer already contained the solution to the main problem (compiler not being able to supply the implicits), but once this was solved, you got bogged down in a syntactical annoyance with the `<: Resource` bound. I've added two detailed solutions for both problems. Sry, didn't manage to finish it yesterday. The short answer didn't seem to help, the long answer required more effort and time...

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found a way to solve your problem by combining a [`ReaderT` monad transformer](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/kleisli.html) with [intersection types](http://dcapwell.github.io/scala-tour/Union%20and%20Intersection%20types.html):

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import cats.~>
import cats.data.ReaderT
import cats.free.Free

object FreeMonads {
  sealed trait Op[A]

  object Op {
    final case class Get[T](name: String) extends Op[T]
    type OpF[A] = Free[Op, A]
    def get[T](name: String): OpF[T] = Free.liftF[Op, T](Get[T](name))
  }

  trait Resource
  trait Format[A]
  trait Definition[A]

  trait Client {
    def get[O <: Resource](name: String)
      (implicit f: Format[O], d: Definition[O]): Future[O]
  }

  type Result[A] = ReaderT[
    Future,
    (Format[A with Resource], Definition[A with Resource]),
    A,
  ]

  class FutureOp(client: Client) extends (Op ~> Result) {
    def apply[A](fa: Op[A]): Result[A] =
      fa match {
        case Op.Get(name: String) =>
          ReaderT {
            case (format, definition) =>
              // The `Future[A]` type ascription makes Intellij IDEA's type
              // checker accept the code.
              client.get(name)(format, definition): Future[A]
          }
      }
  }
}
```

The basic idea behind it is that you produce a `Reader` from your `Op` and that `Reader` receives the values that you can use for the implicit params. This solves the problem of type `O` having instances for `Format` and `Definition`.

The other problem is for `O` be a subtype of `Resource`. To solve this, we're just saying that the `Format` and `Definition` instances are not just instances of any `A`, but any `A` that also happens to be a `Resource`.

Let me know if you bump into problems when using `FutureOp`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's really helpful. Now I need a `Monad` instance for `Result` to be able to run it, right?

Having a run method similar to: `def run[F[_]: Monad, A](intp: Op ~> F, op: OpF[A]): F[A] = op.foldMap(intp)`

Comment: cats docs says “It has a Monad instance so long as the chosen F[_] does.”, and since the F is `Future`, I've imported `cats.instances.futures._` and `cats.implicits._` but still getting errors.

Comment: @racetrack you probably need an implicit `ExecutionContext` in scope.

Comment: @ionuț-g-stan I have one.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Do I understand it correctly that this solution now requires that a `Format` and `Definition` must somehow be provided for *all* possible types `A`? This would restrict `Format`s and `Definition`s to things that are natural in `A`, but I'm not sure where the OP wants to obtain such highly regular and well behaved `Format`s that work for all types of objects. Somehow, it seems to me as if this solution says "assume that we *had* `Format`s and `Definition`s for all `A`...", simply pushing the problem with `Format` one level deeper?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin yes, you're right. In a way, all this follows from the fact that `Get` is generic in `A`, I think. So, as you said, `Get` probably has to carry the instances for `Format` and `Definition`.

Comment: @racetrack I've tried definining a custom `Monad` instance for the `Result` type, but I failed. I don't think one can be defined.

Comment: Thinking more about it, I realize that `Get` is akin to a function that takes a `String` and produces any type the user wants. That can't be done without additional knowledge (expressed by some typeclass constraint on that type `T` or similar).

Comment: @ionuț-g-stan thanks, I'll undo the acceptance for now in order to get hopefully more attention to this question.