# List of classes implementing a certain typeclass

Tags: scala, typeclass

I would like to define a `List` of elements implementing a common type class. E.g.

```
  trait Show[A] {
    def show(a: A): String
  }
  implicit val intCanShow: Show[Int] = new Show[Int] {
      def show(int: Int): String = s"int $int"
  }
  implicit val stringCanShow: Show[String] = new Show[String] {
    def show(str: String): String = str
  }
```

The problem is, how to define a `list = List(1, "abc")` such that it is guaranteed that a `Show` instance for these values is in scope? I would then like to map this list over show like `list map {_.show}`.

Comment: Maybe you could add a note or a tag that tells what libraries you want to use. I would have guessed that you want `scalaz` or `cats`, but by now you have two different solutions which (additionally) rely on `shapeless`...

Comment: I have no special requirements and use whatever works best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will first sketch a solution, and then explain why the naive approach with `List[Any](1, "abc")` cannot work.

---

**What you can do**

Define a wrapper class that can hold instances of type `A` together with instances of `Show[A]`:

```
case class Showable[A](a: A, showInst: Show[A]) {
  def show: String = showInst.show(a)
}
```

Define your list as `List[Showable[_]]`:

```
var showableList: List[Showable[_]] = Nil
```

Maybe define a separate method to fill this list (consider packing the list itself and the builder-method in a class):

```
def addShowable[A: Show](a: A): Unit = {
  showableList ::= Showable[A](a, implicitly[Show[A]])
}
```

Alternatively, you can carefully add a (very tightly scoped) implicit conversion:

```
implicit def asShowable[A](a: A)(implicit s: Show[A]): Showable[A] = 
  Showable(a, s)
```

and then costruct your list as follows (note the explicit type ascription):

```
val showableList = List[Showable[_]](1, "abc")
```

Now you can go through the list and call `show`:

```
showableList.map(_.show)
```

to obtain a list of `String`.

---

**What you cannot do**

You cannot simply define

```
val list: List[Any] = List(1, "abc", <showable3>, ..., <showableN>)
```

and then expect to be able to call `show`, because in order to call `Show.show`, you need *actual `Show` instances*. These things are not some *type-hints* that can be erased at runtime, they are *actual objects*, and they must be supplied by the compiler. Once you have created a `List[Any]`, all is lost, because all the types are merged into an unexpressive upper bound `Any`, and the compiler has no way to inject all the necessary implicits `Show[T_1]`,..., `Show[T_N]`. The argument is very similar to the third section ["Dealing with implicits when defining interpreter for the Free monad" of this lengthy answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172700/bounds-for-type-parameter-of-functionk/49173044#49173044).

Comment: Isn't it easier to use OOP or pattern matching then? I mean, maybe I'm wrong, but let's say type classes in Haskell can't be first-class citizens, besides `Showable` introduces incoherence as user can pass anything to it. So it's not ad-hoc polymorphism (static dispatching) anymore - it breaks the whole paradigm. Dynamic dispatching would be much easier and implement the same logic without implicits and existential types (usually refined to Any).

Comment: It could be even implemented with ad-hoc polymorphism (just not exactly the way author wants), let's say `case class Showable[T](v: T, show:String);
def showable(i: Int) = Showable(i, s"int $i");
def showable(s: String) = Showable(s, s);
List(showable(5), showable("aaa")).map(_.show)` - Still existentials but cleaner. But anything except HLists as Functors would be a workaround.

Comment: So the best part of your answer is "What you cannot do". I think it should be on top :)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way of handling this would be to use the shapeless library. 
I would really reccommend [this book](https://underscore.io/books/shapeless-guide/) which explains shapeless in a clear and concise manner.

Shapeless provides two things that I think will help you in this case:

1. Heterogeneous lists (HList)
2. Polymorphic functions to enable the HList mapping operation.

First import the required libraries ([shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)):

```
import shapeless.{HNil, Poly1, ::}
```

Create a heterogeneous list of whatever types you require. Note the type annotation is only there for clarity.

```
val data : Int :: String :: HNil = 1 :: "hello" :: HNil
```

Create a polymorphic function defining an implicit value for every type you require.

```
object Show extends Poly1 {
    implicit def atT[T: Show] = at[T] (implicitly[Show[T]].show)
}
```

Shapeless provides an extension method for map on a HList to enable applying the show function to every element in the list

```
val result : String :: String :: HNil = data.map(Show)
```

Edited: thanks to @dk14 for the suggested improvement to the definition of the Show polymorphic function.

Answer (score 4):

The core problem here is that you want to create a heterogenous list, something like `List[Int, String]` instead of `List[Any]`. This means you need a different structure that would preserve `Int` and `String` types, but still would be "mappable" like List. The one structure in scala-library that can contain heterogenous types is Tuple:

```
val tuple = (1, "abc")
val result = List(implicitly[Show[Int]].show(tuple._1), implicitly[Show[Int]].show(tuple._2))
```

However, scala-library can't `map` over tuples - you might want some syntax sugar for better readability.

So the obvious solution is [HList](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists) from Shapeless: `Int :: String :: HNil` (or you can use tuple ops and stay with `(Int, String)`)

```
import shapeless._
import poly._


//show is a polymorphic function
//think of it as `T => String` or even `(Show[T], T) => String` 
object show extends Poly1 {
  implicit def atT[T: Show] = at[T](implicitly[Show[T]].show)
}

@ (1 :: "aaaa" :: HNil) map show
res8: String :: String :: HNil = "int 1" :: "aaaa" :: HNil
```

Or you could use `at[Int]`/`at[String]` instead of type-classes, like in @Steve Robinson's answer.

P.S. The lib could be found [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless). They also provide one-liner to get Ammonite REPL with shapeless integrated, so you could try my example out using:

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/milessabin/shapeless/master/scripts/try-shapeless.sh | bash
```

---

Notes:

1. Practically Shapeless solution requires as same amount of maintenance as Tuple-based one. This is because you have to keep track of your `Int` and `String` types anyways - you can never forget about those (unlike in homogenous `List[T]` case). All Shapeless does for you is nicer syntax and sometimes better type inference.
2. If you go with tuples - you can improve readability by using `implicit class` instead of Haskell-like style, or if you still want Haskell-like, there is a [Simulacrum](https://github.com/mpilquist/simulacrum) macro for better type-class syntax.

---

Given that other scala-library-only alternatives just capture type class instances inside some regular class, you could be better off with a regular OOP wrapper class:

```
trait Showable[T]{def value: T; def show: String}
class IntShow(val value: Int) extends Showable[Int]{..}
class StringShow(val value: String) extends Showable[String] {..}

val showables: List[Showable[_]] = List(new Showable(5), new Showable("aaa"))
showables.map(_.show)
```

Looks cleaner and more readable to me :)

If you like to rewrite dynamic dispatching in FP-style:

```
sealed trait Showable
final case class ShowableInt(i: Int) extends Showable
final case class ShowableString(s: String) extends Showable

implicit class ShowableDispatch(s: Showable){
  def show = s match{ //use `-Xfatal-warnings` scalac option or http://www.wartremover.org/ to guarantee totality of this function
    case ShowableInt(i) => ...
    case ShowableString(s) => ...
  }
}

List(ShowableInt(5), ShowableString("aaa")).map(_.show)
```

---

If you really want static dispatching (or ad-hoc polymorphism), given that other solutions introduce `Showable[_]` which is practically `Showable[Any]`:

```
case class Showable[T](v: T, show: String)
def showable(i: Int) = Showable(i, s"int $i") 
def showable(s: String) = Showable(i, s) 
List(showable(5), showable("aaa")).map(_.show)
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclamer: I've made this answer to provide a solution to the concrete development problem, and not the theoretical problem of using typeclass

---

I would do it this way:

```
trait Showable{ def show(): String }

implicit class IntCanShow(int: Int) extends Showable {
  def show(): String = s"int $int"
}

implicit class StringCanShow(str: String) extends Showable {
  def show(): String = str
}

val l: List[Showable] = List(1,"asd")
```

Note that I changed the meaning of the trait Show, into Showable, such that the implementing classes are used as wrapper. We can thus simply require that we want Showable instances 
(and because those classes are implicit, input of the List are automatically wrapped)

Comment: This completely ignores the fact that the `Show`-trait is already implemented. Moreover, this approach introduces implicit conversions. That was not the idea of the question, I think. You have completely thrown all the typeclasses overboard.

Comment: this is anti type-class pattern

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I clearly state that I changed the initial trait. Because I think this is the simplest way to solve the _real problem_ of the OP: having a list of stuff that can be `Show`n.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi what do you mean by `anti type-class pattern` ?

Comment: @Juh_ In the question title and in the question itself it was stated twice that the OP wants a `List` with objects for which certain typeclass is provided. The example with `Show` was preceeded with an `E.g.`. Therefore, I assume that OP actually wants to work with typeclasses, so throwing typeclasses overboard is probably not an option.

Comment: Alright, I get it: this is a training example to play with typeclass. Not an actual development need (for which  you'll agree that typeclass is overkill).